# Outlook 365 shows me my Gmail email but not my Gmail Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, calendar, microsoft-outlook-365

I've added my Gmail account to Outlook 365.  It shows up in my list of email but not my list of calendars.  Is this just a limitation of Outlook 365 and do I have to go through the rigamarole as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) in order to view my Gmail calendar?  It works as expected in the Outlook app on my Android phone.

Comment: You could consider using instead [this procedure](https://www.softwareadvice.com/resources/add-google-calendar-to-outlook/), which is somewhat simpler but slow. Let me know if you would consider it as an answer.

Comment: Will your approach let me read and write to the Gmail calendar?

Comment: @Eric - Have you tried it?

Comment: @Eric: It's supposed to enable it, although the sync may not be immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to subscribe to your Google calendar separately from your Gmail account.  It is a limitation of most email programs, not just Outlook 365.  If you went into Gmail and added your Outlook 365 account to be able to send and receive email from that account, you will also not automatically have your Outlook 365 calendar(s) added to Google calendar.

While it may seem similar to you when initiated it from within an email app on your mobile device, adding a Microsoft or Google account to your mobile device is a very different process (behind the scenes) than adding a Gmail or Outlook email account to a desktop or web app.

If you were to add your Gmail account to your mobile Outlook App using only IMAP or POP, and your device isn't already logged into your Google account, you would see similar behavior as you are currently seeing in Outlook 365.

Comment: Can't agree anymore!

Comment: I think (hope) you mean *"Can't agree more!"* (agree wholeheartedly) rather than *"Can't agree anymore"* (can no longer agree) ✌️

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the specific procedure over here:
[See your Google Calendar in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126).

In short, you have to login to your Google Calendar account and then obtain a URL from there and insert it in Outlook.

**Steps:**

1. Log in to your Google Calendar account.
2. In the left column, click My calendars to expand it, then hover over
   the calendar that you want to add to Outlook as an Internet Calendar
   Subscription. Select the three dots to the right of the calendar
   name, then select Settings and sharing:
3. Near the bottom of the page, under Integrate Calendar, locate the
   Secret address in iCal format box, then select the  The Copy To
   Clipboard button. Copy to clipboard button.
4. In Outlook, select File > Account Settings > Account Settings.
5. On the Internet Calendars tab, click New.
6. Paste the address you copied in step 3, by pressing Ctrl+V, then
   click Add.
7. In the Folder Name box, type the name of the calendar as you want it
   to appear in Outlook, and then click OK.

When you start Outlook, it checks Google Calendar for updates and downloads any changes. While is Outlook open, it also periodically checks for and downloads updates. (Google Calendar tells Outlook how often to check for updates.)

> Note: Changes you make in Outlook aren’t sent to your Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the article
[How to Add Google Calendar to Outlook](https://www.softwareadvice.com/resources/add-google-calendar-to-outlook/) :

**Find Google Calendar URL**

- From the Google apps menu options, click on “Calendar” to open
  a new tab with your Google Calendar
- Copy the URL of your Google calendar from the browser's address bar.

**Add Google Calendar to Outlook**

- In Microsoft Outlook, open the Calendar
- In the left panel, click “Add calendar”
- Select “Subscribe from web”
- Paste the URL of your Google calendar
- Enter a name for the calendar
- Click the down-arrow under “Add to” and select “My calendars” or
  “Other calendars”
- Click “Import” to sync Outlook to your Google Calendar.

You will find more details and screenshots in the article, including
how to move the calendar between “My calendars” and
“Other calendars”, and how to delete the Google Calendar from
Microsoft Outlook.

(Note: As I'm not a user of any of these two calendars, I do not know
how well the two will sync updates.)